# %CommonProgramFiles% and SharePoint Logging Service

Tags: 2010, error, wss-logging

We just moved our Sharepoint (2010 Enterprise) SQL databases to another machine.  Sharepoint is all running well,

however, in the Windows Server (2012 R2) application logs, I am seeing this recurring error:

```
Tracing Service failed to create the trace log file at location specified in SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\WSS\LogDir. Error 0x0: The operation completed successfully. . Traces will be written to the following directory: C:\Users\SHAREP~2\AppData\Local\Temp\.
```

The failing service has the category of `Unified Logging Service`, and the source is `SharePoint Foundation`.

Now, since that is a registry key, I went and looked it up and found it to be:

```
%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\
```

When I type that into Explorer, it resolves to

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\
```

But if I type that into a 32bit file-explorer, it will ([as expected](https://serverfault.com/questions/413320/programfiles-differences-on-64bit-windows)) resolve to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\
```

But the latter directory does not exist.  So, since whatever is causing the Error Log entries can't find the directory that doesn't exist, that tells me that it is a 32bit application trying to use a 64bit environmental variable.

My question is, since Sharepoint is 64bit, why is Sharepoint using a 32bit application for logging?  Actually, my question is, "How do I get this error to go away (without replacing the environmental variable in the registry key)?"

*[update]*

Does anyone have any clues here (or at least a +1 for support)?

When I try to use MS's ULS viewer, with the path of the uls logs set to `\\saintmagnus\c$\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS` like they should be, nothing gets loaded.

Also, I tried manually changing the registry key to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\` to leave out the environmental variable, but it didn't make any difference (maybe I need to restart something to get that to take?)

So the logs are being written to `C:\Users\SHAREP~2\AppData\Local\Temp\`.  I can load them in the ULS viewer from there, but that's not the right place.

So I make sure that the right LOGS folder has modify/read/write permissions set for the farm account.

Why????  What can I try here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I went and made sure what account was attached to the SPTrace Service.  You can find out by looking in Services.msc for `SPTrace`.  It was not the same as the farm account.

Since I am using a domain account for this service (it is a Managed Account in Sharepoint Central Admin) and not a local account, then it needs the proper rights.

So I went and gave read/write/modify rights to the LOGS folder (correct path) to this account.

As soon as I did this, Sharepoint began writing the log entries to the correct location.